# Cannot display Image blob from MySQL in PHP on my live environment, works on dev

Tags: php, mysql, image

I cannot display a blob image from MySQL on my live hosted environment, it works on dev.
I have a getimage.php file that I pass the id of the image to, I am not writing out any text on the page.
Both these methods work perfectly on my development environment.
Simple code:

#### Method 1:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$data   = mysql_result($result, 0,'documentfile');
echo $data;
```

#### Method 2:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$data   = mysql_result($result, 0,'documentfile');
$bImage = imagecreatefromstring($data);
imagejpeg($bImage);
imagedestroy($bImage);
```

I don't get a php error I get the following error:

> The Image http://www.mywebsite.com/getimage.php?id=15" cannot be displayed because it contains errors`

If I hardcode an imagepath on my live environment it works fine:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$data = file_get_contents("../images/sunflowers.jpg");
echo $data;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I moved the header down, now I get a broken image. When the image blob is being converted to an image, does it get temporarily stored on the hard drive? Could it be a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

move your header row futher down, so that php errors can be sent as text insted

```
$data = mysql_result($result, 0,'documentfile');
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $data;
```

that should make you able to read the error,
you could also try to save the image and open it in a texteditor,
or just use the browser `view source`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it was something to do with the database upload from Dev to Live, maybe encoding or something. When I re-uploaded the image files into the Live DB they appeared correctly.

Comment: Please accept your answer if you don't expect to get better ones. Click on the tick left of your answer. (Or accept @PugganSe's answer if to was more helpful to you …)